# concatenating uint16_t and uint32_t values for hashing

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, concatenation

I am trying concatenating (not adding) 2 `uint16_t` struct members and 2 `uint32_t` struct members and assigning the result to `const void *p` for the purpose of hashing. The struct and `concatenation` function that I am trying to implement is as follows.

```
struct xyz {
....
uint32_t a;
uint32_t b;
....
uint16_t c;
uint16_t d;
....
}


const void *p=concatenation(xyz.a,xyz.b,xyz.c,xyz.d)
```

Edited:

I have to use pre-defined hash functions. The most suitable hash function for my task seems to be this.

```
uint32_t hash(const uint32_t p[], size_t n)
{
    //Returns the hash of the 'n' 32-bit words at 'p'
}
```

or

```
uint32_t hash64(const uint64_t p[], size_t n)
{
   //Returns the hash of the 'n' 64-bit words at 'p'
}
```

Comment: _How_ do you want to concatenate? What should the alignment be? What should `concatenation` return? Who owns the memory? How does the hash function know the data type of `p` i.e. how should that work? Why doesn't `xyz` have a `std::hash` specialization instead?

Comment: What means "concatenate" in this context. Do you want to have 0x01 "concatenate" with 0x02 to be 0x0102? Please clarify your question! If so, (void*) can't keep a value with such variable size!

Comment: Wait? This is an assignment? And the professor wants the result of the hash function to be put into a `void*`???

Answer (score 1):

> for the purpose of hashing

In this case, I'd rather prefer providing a custom hash function – or specialise `std::hash` for. For use with standard templates, this might look like this:

```
namespace std // any extension of std namespace is UB
              // sole exception: specialising templates, which we are going to do
{

template <>
struct hash<xyz>
{
    size_t operator()(xyz const& i) const
    {
        // TODO: need to calculate the value from a, b, c, and d appropriately
        return 0;
    };
};

// if xyz is polymorphic, you might need to operate on pointers
// no problem either:
template <>
struct hash<xyz*>
{
    size_t operator()(xyz const* i) const
    {
        return hash<xyz>()(*i);
        // or if hash value is type dependent:
        return i->hash(); // custom virtual hash member function needs to be implented
    }
}

// now you can have
std::unordered_set<xyz> someSet;

void demo()
{
    someSet.insert(xyz());
}
```

(Untested code, in case of errors please fix yourself.)

A list of hashing algorithms which might be used can be found at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

Comment: Are you sure you want an unordered_set of pointers? Your current example has dangling pointers.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No dangling pointers. The instance is `static`. Using pointers depends on use case (e. g. `xyz` being polymorphic), but agree, as a general example that's less appropriate...

Comment: I didn't notice the `static`. You're right.

Comment: Hmmm, makes me think. Maybe you could put everything in a `std::bitset<sizeof xyz>` (maybe even cast?) and take the hash specialization of that? probably UB...

Comment: also: Making your own hash function is not a good idea. I think your suggestion will have a lot of collisions. The `i.b ^ i.a` that is. You want your hash function to have a nice uniform distribution.

Comment: @JHBonarius Agree, now referring to wikipedia only...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to fit into a pointer, the full value can be 32 bits on x86 or 64 bits on x64. I'm going to assume you are compiling for 64 bit machines.

This means you can only fit 2 uint16 and one uint32, or 2 uint32s.

Either way, you would shift the values into a uint64 (`c | (d << 16) | (c << 32)`) and then convert that value to a void*.

Edit: for clarification, you cannot fit all the structs members bit shifted one after another into a single pointer. You need a minimum of 96 bits to hold the packed struct which means at least two 64 bit pointers.

Comment: no, that would work as `a` and `b` are 32 bit. So `a | (b << 16)` will overlap. Anyhow, what would follow? like you say, it will not fit in 64-bit, so how would the hashing function know what to hash? This question needs more clarification before it can be answered.

Comment: Imo the question cannot be solved as presented while including all the members, so that what I've pointed out. Is that not the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider:

Does that hash value need to be portable across systems? If it does, then you will need to be careful to order the bytes the same way on different systems. If not, then the implementation can be simpler.

Do you want to hash every member of the class, and the class has no padding, and no value of a member should be hashed equally to another different value?

If both of these simplifications apply, then your function is fast and easy to implement but violating that precondition will break the hash. If not, then you must serialise the the data into a buffer, which practically means that you cannot simply return a pointer.

---

Here is a super simple implementation for the case that you don't need portability, and you hash all members, and there is no padding:

```
xyz example;
static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<xyz>);
const void* p = &example;
```

Note that this doesn't work with (IEEE-754) float members due to peculiarities of NaN.

---

A more robust solution that can produce hashes that are portable across systems is to use a general purpose serialisation scheme, and hash the serialised result. There is no standard serialisation functionality in C++.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` has problems like: Who owns the memory? What's the type you are going to reinterpret the pointer as?

A more typed solution would be to use `std::array` of `std::byte` then you at least know that you're looking at an array of raw bytes and nothing else:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

auto concat(std::uint32_t a, std::uint32_t b, std::uint16_t c, std::uint16_t d) {
    std::array<std::byte, sizeof a + sizeof b + sizeof c + sizeof d> res;
    std::byte* p = res.data();
    std::memcpy(p, &a, sizeof a);
    std::memcpy(p += sizeof a, &b, sizeof b);
    std::memcpy(p += sizeof b, &c, sizeof c);
    std::memcpy(p += sizeof c, &d, sizeof d);
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::uint32_t a = 1, b = 0;
    std::uint16_t c = 1, d = 0;

    auto res = concat(a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```